# Using a mention as an input to a command

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to create a command for my bot that will go through and remove a specified number of messages from the mentioned user, the command syntax is `.cleanfrom <@user> <numberOfMessages>`.
in order to see how I can identify a user from a mention, I tried printing the input for the name like so.

```
@client.command(aliases=['cf'])
async def CleanFrom(ctx, user, count=5):
    print(user)
```

but it just returns `None`.
How can i use a mention as an input for a command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why it returns `None` but in order to get `discord.Member` object from an argument, you can use converters.

```py
@client.command(aliases=['cf'])
async def CleanFrom(ctx, user: discord.Member, count=5):
    ...
```

This will return you a `discord.Member` object.